# Execute function when the checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-events

I have below function when we check or uncheck the check box (inside the gridview)  it will show the popup and other processing information.

Is there any way to execute this function only when **checkbox is checked and not on unchecked** condition?

Below is my function:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%= gvPRCertInfo.ClientID %> input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {

        var signValue = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(4)').html();

        if (signValue == "Virtual") {

            var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
            confirm_value.type = "hidden";
            confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";

            if (confirm("you have selected virtual do u want to create a new name for this?")) {
                confirm_value.value = "Yes";
            } else {
                confirm_value.value = "No";
            }
            document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
        }
    });
});
```

This is my gridview:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvPRCertInfo" runat="server" GridLines="None"                                                                                  
   CssClass="data responsive">
           <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" SortExpression="">
             <HeaderTemplate>
               <asp:CheckBox ID="chkboxSelectAll" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkboxSelectAll_CheckedChanged" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                   <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCert" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" OnCheckedChanged="chkCert_CheckedChanged" runat="server" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="hdnCertId" runat="server" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CertId") %>' />
                           </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CertificateID" HeaderText="Certificate ID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />

 ................
 .................
```

Would anyone please suggest any ideas on how to execute only when I check the checkbox.

Comment: Use `this.checked` property, It will return `true`/`false`

Comment: `if (!this.checked) return;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this inside the on change function of the checkbox.

```
if($(this).is(':checked') == true)
{

/* Your function code here.*/

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 2):

try this in side the onchange function

Javascript code

```
if(document.getElementById('mycheckbox').checked) {
    console.log("ckecked")
} else {
     console.log("not ckecked")
}
```

jquery code

```
  if ($('#mycheckbox').attr("checked")) {
             console.log("ckecked")
  }else{    
    console.log("not ckecked")
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your support .. :)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr/ "To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the `checked`, `selected`, or `disabled` state of form elements, use the `.prop()` method."

Answer (score 2):

hello my dear i think this will work but still i'm not sure

you can code like below :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myCheckbox').change(function () {
     if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        // fire your function 
        return;
     }
     // not checked
   });
});
```

Comment: sorry some how this one is not working ... thanks for your support

Comment: why is not working can you give me some feedbacks ..??

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr/ "To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the `checked`, `selected`, or `disabled` state of form elements, use the `.prop()` method."

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's is() function:

```
if($("input").is(':checked')) {
  dosomething
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support :)